# how do I Design a mobile App to track other apps

Tags: android, ios, react-native, mobile, mobile-application

Our marketing team use their official WhatsApp to communicate with different vendors. We need to pull that data out to a remote server(in a JSON perhaps).

Is it possible to design an App tracking app that does that? Doesn't have to be real-time, neither we intend to put it in the play store.

Something along the lines of this is also fine:
https://panel.clevguard.com/demo/whatsapp

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid this is not easily possible.
You can find the messages of Whatsapp on the devices of your marketing team.
They are usually stored in something like InternalStorage/WhatsApp/Databases/msgstore-..db.crypt12

as the file extension suggests, those database files are encrypted and you need a key to decrypt them. This key is also stored on the device but you can not get to it, except if you have root access on the device.
If you have root access then this article describes what to do in order to decrypt
https://medium.com/@lakinduakash/decrypt-whatsapp-messages-3cc6da574836

You need:

- Root access
- msgstore.db.crypt12 or similar file from Whatsapp/Databases
- key file obtained from /data/data/com.whatsapp/files/key (Need root access)
- A computer that installed java (JRE) 8+ (Add java to your Path variable if not added to run java command from the command line)
- Download jar file from https://github.com/lakinduakash/wadec12/releases/download/1.0/decrypt12.jar
- Some SQLite browser
  Put all those files into one folder and execute
  java -jar decrypt12.jar key msgstore.db.crypt12 msgstore.db
  which results in a megastore.db file that you can open with the SQLite Browser.

Another alternative could be if your marketing team communicates with the vendors only within a specified network, you could have a network sniffer running waiting for the WhatsApp requests, but as they are (at least supposed to be) end to end encrypted, you shouldn't be able to read the messages so I guess this isn't really a solution.

Comment: how about installing a keylogger ? will that track WhatsApp ?

Comment: I guess even if you manage to track the input of the marketing team, the key logger will not have the responses to those messages, no?

Comment: https://panel.clevguard.com/demo/whatsapp
how are they about to track WhatsApp messages with clevguard.

Comment: My guess is what they want to say on this page is that everything marked as key logger is tracked. The other parts are not.
Or perhaps they found a way to get the key file without root, for example in there intro video they show the permissions that are required. One Is admin access perhaps it allows to get such files. Not sure, sorry